# What typeof(Page) Am I Navigating From?

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-phone-8.1

In the Basic Page template, there is the method `NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e){}`.  How can I check to see what the previous page was?

`if(sender.GetType() == typeof(PreviousPage)){}` does not work!

My primary objective is to know where my data is coming from in clean in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method won't work as `NavigationHelper_LoadState(object sender, LoadStateEventArgs e){}` is being called by *NavigationHelper* and the the *sender* passed is *NavigationHelper* - there is no information passed from which Page the navigation has started.

I don't see any properties in which you could read this information, but you can surely pass your previous type as a parameter:

```
// when navigating:
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page1), this.ToString());

// in target Page:
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parameter == typeof(MainPage).ToString())
        Debug.WriteLine("Previous was MainPage");
}
```

Comment: You are awesome. Answering all my WP8.1 questions! :)

Answer (score 2):

Although one option is to send a parameter with page type, I wouldn't do it because you might need that parameter to pass some other relevant data between pages.

So, I'd rather do something like this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (Frame.CanGoBack)
    {
        PageStackEntry lastPage = Frame.BackStack[Frame.BackStackDepth - 1];
        if (lastPage.SourcePageType == typeof(MainPage))
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
    this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

Comment: +1 I must admit that using BackStack is a better way in most cases. Thought both methods (parameter and backstack) need proper handling on suspending/resuming - but that's of course other issue.